# best practices of accessing db from web application

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web

My question might be wrong but i have doubt about designing web application which accessing MySQL database.

Following conversation was happened between me and my friend.

My friend asked me to create separate user accounts for every user roles of the system and asked me to enable the delete option only to admin users.

```
+-----------+-----------------+                 
|User role  | Db credential   |
+-----------+-----------------+     
|Admin      | Admin           |   
+-----------+-----------------+       
|User       | User            |        
+-----------+-----------------+
```

I said, we could have only one user account to access the db and all other stuffs can be done by authorization principle and I quote "While developing web application we could use multiple db user accounts for every developer but while deploying web application we might use only one user account for a deployed application"

```
+---------+-------------+  
|User role|Db credential|  
+---------+-------------+  
|Admin    | Only one    |  
+---------+user account +  
|User     | for web app |  
+---------+-------------+
```

My friend arguing with me that for avoiding SQL injection we could design the system as he said. I thought its entirely wrong argument to consider.

Please help me to find best practices while designing web application especially with user roles and db user credentials. I'm confused by my friend.

Comment: is your question more on development or user side (eg production) to use more db users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normally you only have one mysql account which can access the database, more accounts for one application (to increase security) make no sense for me because if your systems gets compromised all logins are leaked because they need to defined in your application code.

on the other side you give attackers with many mysql accounts more possibilities to attack.

so what is left for using multiple accounts in one application, ahh access user actions against the database (limit user a with no edit rights etc.).

what a user should do against your database (delete things a, edit things b) should be handled by your application logic, for sure it is good to limit operation access per user (eg don't allow to write into outfile etc.) but not to handle such simple things. the cost (multiple data connection per user) is in my eyes much higher then a good programming logic.

so increase security wich multiple accounts is pointless, use one account with a strong password and let the simple actions edit, delete etc. handel by your programming logic.